# I started commenting my C++ program then got errors

Tags: compiler-errors, c++14

So I had this working and Was about to put it on my gitub when I realized I forgot to comment so I went back and did that and I guess I did something wrong because now I'm getting errors I don't know how to get rid of.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ENVIROMENT //Defines a class.
   {
   public:
   string OS; //Difines a string.
          {
          if (char const* USER = std::getenv("USER")) //Checks for user      name on a Unix-like system.
          {
          OS = "Unix"; //If true (succeded), assigns "Unix" to the variable "SYS".
          }
          else if(char const* USER = std::getenv("USERNAME")) //If last check was false (failed), checks for the username on Windows.
             {
             OS = "Windows"; //If true (succeded), assigns "Windows" to the variable "SYS".
             }
             else
             {
             OS << "Your system is not supported!"; //If both returned false (failed), assignes a "System not supported" message to SYS.
             }
          cout << OS << endl; //Tells the user what system they have or that it is not supported (meaning it doesn't know what OS it is).
          return OS; //Returns OS to the string "OS".
          }
   };

int main()
   {
   ENVIROMENT CHECK; //Calls the class "ENVIROMENT", refers to it as "CHECK".
   CHECK.OS(); //Calls the function (string) "OS" from the class "ENVIROMENT".
   return 0; //Returns a value of 0 if int "main" executed successfuly.
   }
```

Errors:

```
ERROR: 10:11 Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers.
```

and

```
ERROR: 31:4 Type string does not provide a call operator.
```

My question is: what do these errors mean? I know I must be missing something pretty basic.

EDIT: It's supposed to detect the running OS based on the username system variable. Returns "Unix" on unix like systems and "Windows" on Windows. It's purely educational and not meant to be used by itself but can be useful in a more complete program.

Comment: I've provided a working solution in my answer. Here's the link with the working code: http://ideone.com/fwbQVy. You need to compare it with yours to see the differences. It's better that you get rid of all the comments to fix the code itself. You can add comments later.

Comment: @Josh: you should avoid redundant comments in code.  Try to make your code readable.  A line like `OS = "Unix"; //If true (succeded), assigns "Unix" to the variable "SYS".`  does not bring anything to the reader, and only clutters the code.  This make your code a lot less readable.  Your code is quite readable and easy to follow without the comments.  Comments should be limited to a single block explaining the algorithm and/or special consideration about the input, error conditions, etc...  What is commonly know as the 'contract'.  Most functions do not need comments at all, but documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple syntax errors!

Here's a snippet of your code (without comments) that is free code inside the class definition. It should be in some function. You cannot write code like that. Check the live code and compare it with yours.

```
// ...
public:
   string OS;
   {
       if (char const* USER = std::getenv("USER"))
   {
// ...
```

Here's a functional version of your code: http://ideone.com/fwbQVy

**IMPORTANT**
Follow a consistent style for indentation and comments.

Take some time to go through the [C++ Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md).

Comment: oooooooo.k. that didn't work. the IDE didn't give any errors but gcc just threw whole buch EDIT: heres a link thats not ganna fit here. https://github.com/Myersj281/Small-Projects-Cpp/wiki

Comment: @Josh: What didn't work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in your code? Please update your question with your problem statement.

Comment: ok never mind the IDEs built in terminal compiled it fine but sakura didn't

Comment: How did you compile it? Command?

Comment: gcc command in sakura(terminal) failed with errors in the link and builder's(IDE) built in terminal managed to compile it EDIT: the specific command I used (in both) is "gcc ~/checkOS.cpp -o CheckOS"

Comment: Can you post the full command here? All the relevant paths are set?

Comment: It compiled and runs and I (think I) understand the change you made setting the print() function. the full command is edited into my last comment

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution per se, I just wanted to show @Josh how using *a* (not *the* as that doesn't exist) proper coding style, indentation, would make his app (and any app) very readable, with a minimum of comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

// This application tries to deduce the OS by probing from environment strings. 

class Environment
{
public:
  static std::string getOS() 
  {
    // tries to get the OS by getting the username from the environment.
    // returns the name of the OS, or an empty string on error.

    if (std::getenv("USER"))
    {
      return "Unix";
    }
    else if (std::getenv("USERNAME"))
    {
      return "Windows";
    }
    return "";
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::string osName = Environment::getOS();

  if (osName.empty())
  {
    std::cout << "Your system is not supported!\n"; 
    return 1;
  }

  std::cout << "Running under: " << osName << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```